# IE 9 rendering blank as null in xhtml

Tags: xhtml

I am generating page to work across all browsers. When I am using chrome or firefox it's coming as empty which is response from back end but when trying in IE9 it's giving as `null` .

```
<td id = "parentid">
    <h: outputText value ="#{familybean.parentName}" />
</td>
```

Comment: Can you post (or link to) a more complete example that actually demonstrates the problem?

Comment: Familybean is java bean class and parentName is its property  . While in firefox and chrome nothing is shown which is expected as its having no value in bean but in IE its displaying as **'null'** . I want that filed to blank in ie also